# Prove by induction on two variables that there are $n^m$ functions from $\{1, \ldots m\}$ to $\{1, \ldots, n\}$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I am trying to prove following statement:

> $[m,n]$ is a set of functions defined as $f \in [m,n] \leftrightarrow f: \{1,...,m\} \rightarrow \{1,...,n\}$. The size of $[m,n]$ is $n^m$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}_{\gt0}$.

I have tried to prove it but I am not entirely sure about its correctness:

**1)** For the basic step $m=n=1$.

The size of $\{1\} \rightarrow \{1\}$ is $1$. And it equals $1^1 = 1$.

**2)** Then I assume that for some $m,n$ the size $[m,n] = n^m$. Now comes the first problem: should I be proving it for $[m, n+1],[m+1,n],[m+1,n+1]$ or is some of it redundant?

When trying to prove $[m, n+1]$ I rewrite it as $[m,n+1] = (n+1) * (n+1) * (n+1) * ... * (n+1) = (n+1)^m$ but I don't use the induction assumption so is that correct?

Again $[m+1,n] = n*n*...*n = n^{m+1}$

Finally $[m+1,n+1] = (n+1)*(n+1)*...*(n+1) = (n+1)^{m+1}$.

During the process I didn't really used my induction assumption, so I am worried that this wouldn't qualify as a proof by induction. So what would be the correct way to prove this?

Comment: what kind of function is $f$?... injective, surjective, bijective??

Comment: It is enough to perform induction on $m$ (or $n$, but that won't work nicely here), where the statement $P(m)$ is: "For all $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $\#[m,n]=n^m$." Then show $P(0)$ and $P(m)\to P(m+1)$ for all $m$. - Also, you didn't use induction because you handwavingly made use of "$\ldots$" in your proof, which kills the formality of the proof (well, the dots already appear in the definition of $[m,n]$; this should be avoided, e.g. by writinh $\{\,k\in\mathbb N\mid k\le m\,\}$ instead of $\{1,\ldots,m\}$

Comment: @janmarqz that's not really specified there.. it says "set of all functions with domain $\{1,..,m\}$ and codomain $\{1,..,n\}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you, your comment is the best answer. If you could post it as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Size of $[m,n]$ denotes number of functions $f\colon\{1,2,\ldots\,m\}\to \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. For any element in $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ we have n choices to assign it. So, for any two elements we have $n\times n$ choices to assign.Continuing like this, for $m$ elements we have $n\times n \ldots \times n=n^m$ choices . So there are $n^m$ number of functions.

Comment: Yeah I understand all this, but I need proper proof by induction.. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you let one of the variables stay a variable and do induction on the other variable. I will let your intuition tell you which should be the induction variable.

Comment: So to prove P(n,m) for all n, m show P(n, 1) for arbitrary n, then show if P(n,m) P(n, m+1) (or other way around)